# C++ Opencv Undefied Refrence contrib module

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am getting the error Undefined refrence to cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer.

My header looks like this

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
```

The line that is causing the error is

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
```

I have also tried this with the same error

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer(0, DBL_MAX);
```

I'm compiling the program with:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv61 -luv4lext -Wl,-rpath,'/usr/lib/uv4l/uv4lext/armv6l'   opencv_test.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_highgui -o opencv_test
```

and I am getting the error:

```
opencv_test.cpp:(.text+0x5d8):undefined refrence to 'cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(int,double)'
```

The strange thing is that the other libs seem to be linked fine so I don't know how just one library would be improperly linked.

This is running in on a raspberry pi using the raspbian distro

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to figure out what was happening... I used apt-get remove to remove the contrib module and then re-installed it... I now believe that this was a symptom of a larger linking error because I have 2 different versions of opencv running on the same machine... In any event I hope this helps someone out.